# (.text+0xf98): referencia a `Desfire::csnTISC(char**)' sin definir

Tags: c++, librería

Estoy tratando de compilar un archivo c++ para que me guarde un .exe pero al momento de hacer esta linea de comando:

```
g++ -Wall -o oficial.exe oficial.o pn532.o pn532_rpi.o -lwiringPi
```

Me marca este error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: oficial.o: en la función `isCardPresent()':
oficial.cpp:(.text+0xf98): referencia a `Desfire::csnTISC(char**)' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: oficial.o: en la función `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
oficial.cpp:(.text+0x1050): referencia a `Desfire::Desfire()' sin definir
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

La verdad no sé mucho de esto, apenas estoy orientandome en c++.

Este es el archivo que quiero compilar (se llama oficial.cpp):

```
#include "Buffer.h"
#include "Desfire3.h"
#include "DesFireKey.h"
#include "Secrets.h"
#include "Utils.h"
#include "pn532.h"
#include "pn532_rpi.c"

Desfire tisc;
std::string rfidUid = ".";

bool isCardPresent(){
    char* u8_UID[7];
    bool Tarjetapresente = false;
    if (tisc.csnTISC(&u8_UID[7])){
        rfidUid = "";
    }
    return Tarjetapresente;
}

int main() {
    printf("Se creo la instancia correctamente\n");
    while (true){
        if (isCardPresent()){
            printf("La tarjeta esta presente");
        }
    }
}
```

Esta es la funcion csnTISC de mi archivo Desfire3.cpp:

```
bool Desfire::csnTISC(char* u8_UID[7]){

nfc.PN532_SamConfiguration(&nfc);

    if (nfc.PN532_ReadPassiveTarget(&nfc, &u8_UID, PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, 1000)) 
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Y esa misma función en mi encabezado (Desfire3.h):

```
bool csnTISC(char* u8_UID[7]);
```

No comprendo muy bien porque me da el error, ¿Alquien que me pueda apoyar?

Comment: A caso compilas cada archivo por separado y luego los unes con línea de comando que indicaste?

Comment: No para nada, en el archivo principal (oficial.cpp) es donde llamo a todos los archivos... y ya ese archivo es el que intento compilar.

Comment: Lo otro de pn532 de la linea de comando es referente a una librería que estoy utilizando de nfc.

Comment: Entonces por qué en la línea de comandos escribes `.o` en lugar de `.cpp`?

Comment: Por que primero hago otro comando para que el archivo .cpp se convierta a .o

Comment: g++ -Wall -c oficial.cpp -lwiringPi -I../../

Comment: Entonces si estás compilando por separado. También puedes compilar todos juntos.